# PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl JPA hibernate naming works for dev/local but not in testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, naming-strategy

My table name is in camelcase and the hibernate (v5) naming is PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl which works when running the application using @SpringBootApplication but when it is used in testing and using @DataJpaTest it turns the camelcase name to all uppercase and so the test will not get executed.

I have also made sure that I have two separate application.yml one for dev and one for testing and the one for testing works

This is how I declared my naming which worked for dev/local:

```
jpa:
  hibernate:
    naming:
      physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

The table name is declare as following: `@Table(name = "ClinicalUser")`
Getting the following error:

```
ERROR 35284 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Table "CLINICALUSER" not found
```

I like to mention again that this worked when used on dev/local env.

I have checked all the other related questions and they either couldn't connect to their test application.yml or they had different problems with different naming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont really understand what was exactly wrong but I had the h2 dependency on my pom.xml file and after removing that and adding `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)`
under the `@DataJpaTest` it worked.